# Can I use Zoho and AWS SES on one domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Hello my company requires to have two email services for one domain. THey are using zoho and AWS SES. Zoho for company main persons and AWS SES for employees.

I have listed mx records of zoho and AWS SES in different priorities. Zoho being in 10, 20, 30 priority and AWS being 40 and so on. And for SPF record, I have combined two records to one.

example:
v=spf1 include:zoho.com include:amazonses.com ~all

Now, Sending email in zoho and AWS workmail works.
But when receiving emails, it only goes to zoho and not in AWS workmail.

How can I work for both?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use two email provider to handle incoming emails for two different groups of user using the same domain.

You will need to designate two different domains, one for each.

I suggest every user in the company get a standard AWS workmail, and then forward Zoho email to AWS for users that need Zoho.

Alternatively, you can use a subdomain for users that need Zoho email eg rodm@zoho.example.com.